# I2C Initialization and draining feature

Tags: initialization, i2c, gpio

I'm a beginner. I'm trying to understand about I2C Initialization of TMP102. It is a temperature sensor. It is connected via I2C. So, the initialization must be of I2C. But, my leader told we have to initialize GPIO also in this case, since interrupt pin is connected via GPIO. He also told it is not necessary in other cases. I couldn't understand the original purpose.

Why do we initialize GPIO?
In other cases, where does the slave's interrupt pin gets connected?(if not in GPIO)

Also, in case of large message, TX/RX FIFO may not fit. So, draining feature is used (XDR/RDR bit is set). What exactly is draining feature and what it does?

Answer (score 1):

```
Why do we initialize GPIO?
```

Since interrupt pin is connected via GPIO.

```
In other cases, where does the slave's interrupt pin gets connected?
```

If slave has an interrupt pin, you SHOULD initialize corresponding GPIO/IOMUX.

Some slave devices may not contain interrupt. In that case, no need to initialize any GPIO.

```
Summary:
```

You should initialize ALL GPIO/IOMUX for all input/output from processor to slave device.

Comment: Thanks! So, if there is an interrupt pin in Slave, it must be connected via GPIO only. Am I right?

Comment: Yes @Gomu .. Anyway, what you should understand is `You should initialize ALL GPIO/IOMUX for all input/output from processor to slave device.` Then you can consult your hardware counterpart for details of which and all GPIO/IOMUX are used by that particular peripheral, and that GPIO/IOMUX details (like: frequency, impedance etc.), You can use these details for initializing corresponding GPIO/IOMUX.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have updated my question. Could you explain me that also?

Comment: @Gomu `What exactly is draining feature and what it does?` Whether you are asking about **Open drain Enable and Opern drain Disable** feature in IOMUX settings??

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure about it. The TRM is [here](http://wiki.titaniumrat.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=embedded:swpu231aj.pdf). Pg 4543. Kindly check it out. Thank you.

Comment: @Gomu Ok. I'll check it and come back.